# Speech Recognition in Turkish

Tags: java, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, lego-mindstorms

Hello I'm working on a project about controlling a robot with Turkish voice commands.

As I search on internet all I can find are Sphinx like speech recognition libraries but they don't support my language.

Is there any possible ways to form my own library for about 20 different commands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it's possible.  The only thing you are missing is the Turkish acoustic model, which I am not sure if there are any free ones available. You can follow the great [sphinxtrain tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam) to train one yourself (which is probably the biggest task in this project). You will then need to plug your commands into a grammar file (JSGF is supported as far as I remember).  The accuracy should be rather good (99% should be the expectation).

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but for the reference, you can use Google Speech API in 110 languages
https://cloud.google.com/speech/

It works online, but there is an [offline version for android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)